# Can I initialise the zoom to be set to 100% in HTML, javascript or CSS when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi im having some trouble with my some form elements getting reorganised on a page zoom / zoom in zoom out, so I want to set the page zoom to 100% everytime the page is reloaded is this possible, or i there another way for force the form elements to stay fixed on a page zoom / unzoom ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you force browser Zoom to 100%, set zoom property on page load

```
document.body.style.zoom = 1.0
```

But, zoom is not a standard property for all browser

```js
var scale = 'scale(1)';
document.body.style.webkitTransform = scale; // Chrome, Opera, Safari
document.body.style.msTransform = scale;    // IE 9
document.body.style.transform = scale;     // General
```

```html
   <span> Test </span>
```